# How to use IE 11 in webdriverio.io v7

Tags: webdriver

After some research, I am trying to use the following code in the wdio.conf.js file in order to use IE 11 with webdriver.io version 7. It still isn't working. Any suggestions?

This is what I am using in wdio.conf.js.

line 1:

```
const drivers = {
    ie: {
        version: "3.150.1", // or whatever latest is
        arch: "ia32", // forces use of 32 bit driver
        baseURL: "https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com"
    },
};

exports.config = {
     // ...
```

line 65, with the browserName,

```
    capabilities: [{
    
        // maxInstances can get overwritten per capability. So if you have an in-house Selenium
        // grid with only 5 firefox instances available you can make sure that not more than
        // 5 instances get started at a time.
        maxInstances: 5,
        browserName: 'ie',
        
        acceptInsecureCerts: true
        // If outputDir is provided WebdriverIO can capture driver session logs
        // it is possible to configure which logTypes to include/exclude.
        // excludeDriverLogs: ['*'], // pass '*' to exclude all driver session logs
        // excludeDriverLogs: ['bugreport', 'server'],
    }],
```

line 131:

```
    path: '/wd/hub',    
    
    services: [
        ['selenium-standalone', {
            logPath: 'logs',
            installArgs: { drivers }, // drivers to install
            args: { drivers } // drivers to use
        }]
    ],
```

The above information is largely based on https://webdriver.io/docs/selenium-standalone-service.
I have downloaded IEServerDriver.exe and Selenium Server (Grid) from https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/ and started them on their respective ports.
This is the error I'm seeing:

```
  ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 500 d
ue to session not created: Unable to create session from {
[0-0]   "desiredCapabilities": {
[0-0]     "browserName": "ie"
[0-0]   },
[0-0]   "capabilities": {
[0-0]     "firstMatch": [
[0-0]       {
[0-0]         "browserName": "ie"
[0-0]       }
[0-0]     ]
[0-0]   }
[0-0] }
```

If anyone has succeeded in using IE 11 with webdriver.io version 7, I welcome suggestions. I have also tried services such as   `services: ['iexplorerdriver'],`, but to no avail. I see that it's not listed at https://webdriver.io/docs/gettingstarted for this version.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way, and I think this will work for you.

http://v4.webdriver.io/guide/services/iedriver.html

This was written for webdriver 4, but it still works in webdriver 7.
I used these capabilities:

```
capabilities: [{
    maxInstances: 1,
    browserName: 'internet explorer',          
    acceptInsecureCerts: false
   }],
```

For services, I think this is all that is needed:

```
services: ['iedriver'],
```

Of course, you have to install it via command line first:

```
npm install wdio-iedriver-service --save-dev
```